# Why does python product incorrect values with dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to produce a python dictionary that results in the following:

```py
{'student_1': [{2017: 3}, {2018: 4}], 'student_2': [{2017: 60}, {2021: 153}], 'student_3': [{2015: 45}]}
```

The data comes from a database table that is tabular and looks like this:

```
| yearfield | count | name      |
| --------- | ----- | --------- |
| 2017      | 3     | student_1 |
| 2018      | 4     | student_1 |
| 2017      | 60    | student_2 |
| 2021      | 153   | student_2 |
| 2015      | 45    | student_3 |
```

I can produce the desired formatted dictionary, however, each key in the dictionary is getting the values replaced with the last key's values in the database table.

Below is my code:

```py
# chartdata is a fetchall() from a executed database query
q={}
for a,b,c in chartdata:
    v=[]
    q[a]=b
    v.append(q)
    datasetnew[c] = v

# Results
{'student_1': [{2015: 45}], 'student_2': [{2015:45}], 'student_3': [{2015:45}]}
```

I tried a few different lines of code, however, none produced the correct results.

For example, this change put ALL the values for each student in every students key.

```py
v=[]
q={}
for a,b,c in chartdata:
    q[a]=b
    v.append(q)
    datasetnew[c] = v
```

Comment: Are you sure you want lists with dictionaries that only have **one key**? Why not a dictionary with multiple keys, like `{'student_1': {2017: 3, 2018: 4}, 'student_2': {2017: 60, 2021: 153}, 'student_3': {2015: 45}}`? That looks more useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this more easily with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

datasetnew = defaultdict(list)
for year, count, name in chartdata:
    datasetnew[name].append({ year: count })
```

Result is:

```
{
    'student_1': [{2017: 3}, {2018: 4}], 
    'student_2': [{2017: 60}, {2021: 153}], 
    'student_3': [{2015: 45}]
}
```

However, I wonder why you would create lists of dictionaries that each only have one key? It would seem more useful to combine those little dictionaries into one dictionary per student:

```
datasetnew = defaultdict(dict)
for year, count, name in chartdata:
    datasetnew[name][year] = count
```

This produces this structure:

```
{
    'student_1': {2017: 3, 2018: 4}, 
    'student_2': {2017: 60, 2021: 153}, 
    'student_3': {2015: 45}
}
```

Comment: That is a really good point.  I have control over how the output is produced.  This simplifies things for me.  Thanks